# Como declaro un atributo de tipo Date en Typescript (Angular 6)

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, angular6

Estoy usando NodeJS + Angular6 para hacer una aplicación web y tengo un modelo llamado "Empleado". Mi problema es que tengo un archivo llamado "empleadoModel.ts" que tiene el código:

```
//Importamos el archivo que necesitamos
import { tipoEmpleadoModel } from './tipoEmpleadoModel';
import { ciudadModel } from './ciudadModel';

/**
 * Entidad empleado
 */
export class Empleado {

    cedula: string;
    nombre: string;
    apellido: string;
    fecha_nacimiento: date;
    fecha_ingreso: date;
    genero: string;
    direccion: string;
    salario: number;
    ciudad: ciudadModel;
    telefono: string;
    entevistaAceptada: boolean;
    email: string;
    tipoEmpleado: tipoEmpleadoModel;

}
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el proyecto sale el siguiente error:

```
Cannot find name 'date'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza `Date` en las propiedades de tu clase.

```
fecha_nacimiento: Date;
fecha_ingreso: Date;
```